# How to create a dynamic tree using JavaScript from an Array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array let say `A[A.A1.A2,A.A1.A3,A.B1.B2,B.B1.B2,C.C1.C2]`

Now I have to create a Tree Structure like following using javascript

```
A
  A1
     A2
     A3
  B1
     B2
B1
  B1
    B2
C
  C1
    C2
```

Can anybody give me some idea how to do that?

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: What’s your array format? Do you need the output as text or structured HTML? And most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is you *actual* array starting point. Are those strings? Objects? What? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: You want to display it on output or you want it as a datastructure ?

Comment: Hi MTCoster,type of array is string and output is structure HTML.I have not tried anything so far and not understood from where I can start.If you give me some idea I will start from there.

Comment: I would start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [there](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)..

Comment: I have check the article on w3school https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_treeview but this is not dynamic tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the strings, split them, store the items and then iterate over all items by checking *if the previous data set has the same value*. *If not*, assign a new node and store the next level in the `levels` array.

Then, replace `last` with the `temp` array.

The main logic is wrapped in a helper array, which stores the last inserted nodes of the level. This requires a sorted data set.

```js
var array = ['A.A1.A2', 'A.A1.A3', 'A.B1.B2', 'B.B1.B2', 'C.C1.C2'],
    tree = [],
    levels = [tree],
    last = [];

array.forEach(s => {
    var temp = s.split('.');
    temp.forEach((name, i) => {
        if (last[i] === name) return;        
        levels[i].push({ name, children: levels[i + 1] = [] });
    });
    last = temp;
});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina,Thank you very much for your help on this.Can you please help me to traverse tree?

Comment: where is your specific problem?

Comment: Do Not have much Idea about forEach so trying to using below code       
            for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
      console.log("Mother : "+tree[i].name);
   var childArray = tree[i].children;

   for(var j = 0; j < childArray.length; j++){

  console.log("Child :"+childArray[j].name);
  var childArrayC=tree[i].children[j].children;
  console.log(childArrayC.length);
  

   }

}

Comment: But need to use recurring as you used earlier.

Comment: why not ask another question. it is easier when you add your code and the expected result in a question, than to ask things in the comments.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion.I will do.